# Why does a process that is gained from a restricted diffusion process fulfill the Markov property?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

Let $\{X_t,t \geq0\}$ with state space $[0,1]$  be a regular diffusion process. Assume that $0$ and $1$ are exit boundaries.

Then, $\{X^*_t,t\geq0\}$ is prescribed to be the process confined to the sample paths involving ultimate absorption at 1.

Which formal argument(s) can be applied to confirm that $\{X^*_t, t\geq 0\}$ is a Markov process?